# Opcache clears too quickly

Tags: php, opcache

I have setup my website on a new hosting (virtual cloud), however I am looking at the opcache and the `scripts` not being used for say `a minutes or so` are removed from the cache.

So is there a way to stop it? or is it a normal behaviour?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what are the opcache settings in your php.ini?

Comment: What is the value of " "opcache.max_accelerated_files"?  what happens if you set "opcache.validate_timestamps = 0" ?

Comment: opcache.max_accelerated_files = 2000

Comment: Do you have more than 2000 files?

Comment: set validate_timestamps=0, then it is only possible to reset the cache if the server is restarted or opcache_reset is manually called.  And.. by chance, are you calling opcache_reset() from anywhere?

Comment: no im not calling opcache_reset() anywhere

Answer (score 2):

There is configuration for that actually.
`opcache.revalidate_freq=2`, the default value is 2 seconds, opcache will try to check for timestamps every 2 seconds and if the files are changed it will revalidate. 
You can change the value to match your needs, or you can just turn timestamp check off using this conf `opcache.validate_timestamps=0`, but in this case each time you deploy code to production you have to restart php-fpm (if you are using php-fpm) and web server

`opcache.revalidate_freq=2` or any integer value

`opcache.validate_timestamps=1` or `opcache.validate_timestamps=0`

Comment: By using `opcache.validate_timestamps` to `0`, option `opcache.revalidate_freq` will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to define `validate_timestamps=0` in php.ini. Beware of this though - if you upload any changes to your PHP files you will need to restart either Apache (if you use mod_php5) or PHP5-FPM, or clear the opcache manually.

For details on how to clear the opcache manually you basically have to create a PHP file with `opcache_reset()` and run it, but this has to be in the same SAPI as your other files - i.e. run by PHP5-FPM if that is what is serving the rest of your files.
http://ihaveabackup.net/2013/10/19/invalidating-the-opcache-in-php-5-5/